# mysql odbc not saving contents of table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql

I have a client control which takes a textbox a button and applys what ever is written to my html on my asp page using jquery/javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $('[name*= "Button1"]').click(function () {
            var x = $('[name*= "TextBox1"]').val();
            var newdiv = $("<div></div>").html(x).attr('id', 'test');

            $('#test1').append(newdiv);
            $('[name*= "Table1"]').text($('#test1').html());
            $('[name*= "TextBox1"]').val('');

            return false;

        });
    });  
</script>
<p>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" name="TextBox1" runat="server" Rows="3" 
        Height="47px" Width="638px"></asp:TextBox>
</p>
<p>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Post Message" Width="98px" 
        onclick="Button1_Click" /></p>
<p>
    <asp:Table ID="Table1" name="Table1" runat="server" Width="488px"></asp:Table>
</p>

<div id="test1"></div>

</asp:Content>
```

When it does this I also output the contents to a table(unformatted) so in the table I get things that look like this `<div id="test">wsefwefwef</div><div id="test">wefwefwef</div>` <- random buttons I pressed in the textbox and clicked my button. This all works fine.

But when I try to save the contents of my Tabel1 to mysql using odbc nothing is saved?

```
    {
        string theUserId = Session["UserID"].ToString();
        OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=localhost; Database=gymwebsite; User=x; Password=x;");
        cn.Open();

        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO WallPostings (UserID, Wallpostings) VALUES ('UserID="+theUserId+"','"+Table1+"')", cn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


    }
}
```

can anyone help ammend my connection/sql syntax c# as no data is being inserted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `ExecuteReader` when you should probably be calling [`ExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbccommand.executenonquery.aspx).

Comment: Can you please make sure that the command text that you're generating is valid, and that your connection string is right (go here to make sure http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql#p20, cos it looks wrong at the moment). Make sure that your connections actually open. Also make sure you have a WallPostings table. Please post the error messages that you get when attempting to insert.

Answer (score 0):

You should you `Table1.InnerHTML` or `Text` as `Value`. And use `ExecuteNonQuery`.